Vite React Typescript is always showing red underlines
I'm familiar with ViteReact projects because I've done dozens of them, but now I wanted to do my personal big project with Ts beacuse of the size of the project and so that it's easier for me to operate but I made more mess.
My tsconfig.json
/* tsconfig */
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },'include': ["src","src/*","src/**/*", "src/**/**/*","src/*.tsx","src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/**/*.tsx"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
} 


I'll also provide one of many files that has errors of this type:

'Routes' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Routes'?ts(2749)
type Routes = /unresolved/ any

and this is
for this code
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import MainPage from "./MainPage/Main/MainPage";
import React from "react";
import Locations from "./LocationsPage/Locations";
import Clients from "./ClientsPage/Clients";
import Users from "./UsersPage/Users";
import About from "./AboutPage/About";

export default const App: React.FC = () => {
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
      <Route path="/main" element={<MainPage />} />
      <Route path="/clients" element={<Clients />} />
      <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
      <Route path="/locations" element={<Locations />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>;
};


I'm sorry for messy code, but I have no idea what is going on
And I've tried all of the internet advices and stuff,changing typescript versions, adding extenstions, changing anything that i read on the internet and even tried myself something but I guess I don't know enough of it to figure it out myself

Note that your App function doesn't currently return anything.

Yeah I've changed that, the problem is that when I run npm run dev the components show every element in browser, it works fine but only those red lines cant be removed

I've got the same problem with the red underlines using the shadcn install instructions here:
https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/vite
